# Passing the value from the form to another page

Tags: python, django

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_code = generate_code(8)
        subject = 'ver code' 
        message = user_code
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Registration.objects.create(fio=request.POST['fio'],mail=request.POST['mail'],code=user_code)
            send_mail(subject, message,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[mail],fail_silently=False)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('endreg')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'registers/detail.html', {'form': form})

def endreg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("key")
            try:
                user = Registration.objects.get(code=code_use)
                user.verification = True
                user.save() 
                messages.warning(request, u'thanks.')
            except:
                messages.warning(request, u'error.')
    else:
        form = NameForm1()
    return render(request, 'registers/endreg.html', {'form': form})
```

I have 2 fields in the form. when you submit the form to the server, a random confirmation code is generated and sent to this mail
how on page 2, where is the code input field, display to which mail it was sent?
1 page detail
2 page endreg.
how to send the sender email to the endreg page?

Comment: you are storing mail address in registration model, you can fetch the email from there in 2nd view

Comment: @ruddra
I understand that I can display any email on this page. but how can I, after the form sent to page 2, bring out specifically the email to which the code was sent now

Comment: You should save the code to the created `Registration` object

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, I missed this point in the post, but I save the code in the model. Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django sessions. It can store the data.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

```
def fun(request):
    # this is the function where we setting the key value in session
    request.session["name"] ="your name"
    return HttpResponse("Response here")`
```

```
def fun2(request):
    # this is the function where we getting the session key value
    name = request.session.get("name", " ")
    return HttpResponse("Response here")
```

Comment: and how to transfer session key from the first to the second function?

Comment: I edited the above solution to show you the small usage of sessions.Django Sessions are just wonderful.